# puppy linux boot error

Tags: linux, boot, gparted, puppy-linux

First let me give you some context:

I run into SMART disk error 301 after a factory reset of windows, resulting in an unbootable windows drive.
Luckily I had a partition of Ubuntu 22.04 with 60GB allocated, and that boots fine (error 301 still shows on every boot).
I completely wiped the windows partition resulting in ~900GB of unallocated space.

I wanted to assign the free space to my current Ubuntu partition by dragging the unallocated space to the right of my ext4 partition and enlarging it:

[image]

Therefore I created a live puppy linux to do that but it fails to boot. Here are the error logs displayed:

[image]

To my untrained eye looks like it is searching for puppy sfs file inside nvme0n1p5 which is actually part of my SSD drive, instead of the USB /dev/sda drive where `puppy_fossapup64_9.5.sfs` is actually located

What exactly is going on here? How should I approach this problem? I think it is worth mentioning that I tried to boot from Gparted live too, and that fail to boot too, however there were no logs visible on screen. I think this points to some BIOS problems.